# Interleave two columns of a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
 GN  SN  
  a   0.1   
  b   0.2   
  c   0.3   
  d   0.4   
  e   0.4 
  f   0.5
```

I would like the following output:

```
 GN    
  a      
  0.1      
  b      
  0.2      
  c    
  0.3
```

Can anyone help me? How to "interleave" the elements of the second column to the elements of the first column to gain the desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let's create some data:

```
dd = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = LETTERS[1:10])
```

Next, we need to make sure the `y` column is a character and not a factor (otherwise, it will be converted to a numeric)

```
dd$y = as.character(dd$y)
```

Then we transpose the data frame and convert to a vector:

```
as.vector(t(dd))
```

However, a more pertinent question is **why** you would want to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much csgillespie! And if my data.frame were composed of more than two columns  that I posted (ex: "GN", "SN", "GN1", "SN1", "GN2", "SN" etc), the apply function is the best way to do the work on the entire data.frame?

Comment: @Bfu38 It depends on what you want to do. Try and see!