# How to intersect two columns in r?

Tags: r, intersect

I have a data frame as following and I want to intersect them to become one column.

```
ID<-c('>1','>2','>3','>4','>5')
TYPE<-c('A','B','O','A','B')
old<-data.frame(ID,TYPE)
old

  ID TYPE
  >1    A
  >2    B
  >3    O
  >4    A
  >5    B
```

I want to merge them and become a new data set to look like this.

```
  NEW_VAR 
  >1  
   A  
  >2    
   B
  >3    
   O
  >4    
   A
  >5    
   B
```

I try the following code, but it does not work.

```
intersect(old$ID, old$TYPE)
```

But it shows

```
character(0)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would call that a interleaving, there are several similar questions if you [search for that term instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400931/interleave-two-columns-of-a-data-frame)

Comment: why do you want it this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the desired result you could try:

```
c(t(old))
 [1] ">1" "A"  ">2" "B"  ">3" "O"  ">4" "A"  ">5" "B"
```